# Relation between BSS and Turing models

Tags: np-hardness, turing-machines, np, p-vs-np, computing-over-reals

$P_\mathbb R$ is the set of languages decidable in polynomial time over the real $BSS$ machine defined in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blum%E2%80%93Shub%E2%80%93Smale_machine.

Let $0-1-P_\mathbb R=\{L\in\{0,1\}^*:L\in P_\mathbb R\}$.

> Is it known $NP\subseteq 0-1-P_\mathbb R$ holds?

> What is the consequence if $NP\subseteq 0-1-P_\mathbb R$ holds?

Comment: Could you define what a $BSS$ machine is for those unfamiliar?

Comment: In https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/030439759300063B it is proved that the additive $BSS$ machines (no multiplication or division) capture $P/poly$ over Boolean inputs. I don't know what happens if we allow multiplication and/or division.